# OpenFiler NAS Installation

Tags: network-attached-storage, openfiler, network-storage

I am planning on installing openfiler (first time) on a Intel Core2Duo 4GB Ram with 2 x 2TB Sata Disks.

Do I need to install openfiler on a separate disk and then use 2 x 2TB as Data drives, or can I install Openfiler on the Primary (1st Disk) and still use the remaining space for my data.

This is for 50 users maximum on a gigabit network, the machine would have a single gigabit nic.

Or

Shall I try to setup Opensolaris (oraclesolaris express or indiana) as a NAS box using ZFS ?

Will be greatful for your insight and suggestions !
Kind Regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To me it makes more sense to keep the OS separate from the data.  That way you can do upgrades to one without affecting the other. Or you can add additional data drives or replace one without risking the OS.